# Textview under imageview on Linearlayout

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm working on a project, basically I had to write an XML file with 3 horizantalScrollViews. Each one of them represents items from an in app store. In order to make items horizantal I used LinearLayout and I could place images correctly. The problem is I can't add textviews under images.

Particular XML part I'm trying to fix

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/HSV1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/HSV2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.13">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/HSVL1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/money"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="16.95 TL"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
```

Comment: Change the orientation of the LinearLayout to vertical.

Comment: Your LinearLayout has ``android:orientation="horizontal"`` change it to ``android:orientation="vertical"`` for the text view to be below the ImageView

Answer (score 1):

Change the `android:orientation` to `android:orientation="vertical"`

Comment: I only want to place the textviews under the images so changing orentation does not help.

Comment: the textview will be under your image if you change your orientation

Comment: and if you want to align the text, remove the margin

Answer (score 0):

Try This -

```
<HorizontalScrollView
android:id="@+id/HSV1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scrollbars="none"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/HSV2"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.13">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/HSVL1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/money"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="16.95 TL"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Draw what you want as image and post here, because it is not clear what you want to do!